# Accessing File by File Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I developed an application. In that I am uploading a file by file upload. Now I want to access the file which is uploaded. Right now I am accessing the file by giving name.

Below is my code:

```
if(PostedFile !=null && PostedFile.ContentLength>0 )
            {

                MyFile = Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
                PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/UploadedFile/", MyFile)));
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFile/aab.html"));
            }
```

I want to access the file which is saved in the UploadedFile folder by the use of StreamReader. Right now I am giving the same file which is selected by me in file upload.

I have also tried this code:

```
if(PostedFile !=null && PostedFile.ContentLength>0 )
            {

                MyFile = Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
                PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/UploadedFile/", MyFile)));
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(MyFile));
            }
```

But the debugger shows the error in stream reader line:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\aab.html'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question.

Here is my updated code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(PostedFile.FileName));
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: i would save it in a temp file. use the Path.GetTemp method to get a unique temp filename

Comment: @thefiloe i have to save it in my application.